# How to loop through an array with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an empty dropdown list that is dependent on the value from another dropdown. I want to write it with vanilla JS not Jquery that will populate the dropdown with the sample data as shown below

Below is the sample data:

```
[{"1":"ABA NORTH"},{"2":"ABA SOUTH"},{"3":"AROCHUKWU"},{"4":"BENDE"},{"5":"IKWUANO"},{"6":"ISIALA NGWA NORTH"},{"7":"ISIALA NGWA SOUTH"},{"8":"ISUIKWUATO"},{"9":"OBINGWA"},{"10":"OHAFIA"},{"11":"OSISIOMA"},{"12":"UGWUNAGBO"},{"13":"UKWA EAST"},{"14":"UKWA WEST"},{"15":"UMUAHIA NORTH"},{"16":"UMUAHIA SOUTH"},{"17":"UMU - NNEOCHI"}]
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="states" id="profileapplicationform-lga_id">
<option value="">Select one</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(e){
        var select = document.getElementById("profileapplicationform-state_origin_id");
        select.addEventListener('change', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: baseurl,
                data: {state_origin_id: this.value},
                success: function(data){
                    var list = document.getElementById("profileapplicationform-lga_id");
                    var html ='';
                    for (var i =1; i<data.length; i++){
                        html+= '<option value="' +data[i][0]+ '">' +data[i][1]+ '</option>';
                    }
                    list.append(html);;
                },              
            }); 
        });
    }
</script>
```

Whenever I select the main value, the dependent dropdown returns empty on the select tag but the sample data above is shown whenever I view the response under the network tab. Please assist here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways you could do this using pure javascript.

Once you receive your array of data from your GET request, you could use a for loop to iterate through the `data` and create one big html string (`htmlToInsert`) of each `<option>` with the relevant data inside.

---

> [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns an array whose elements are arrays corresponding to the enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs found directly upon object.

Then you can use [array destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the `key` and `value` pair.

Once you have that, you can simply insert it with [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

---

Note: for performance reasons, it is best practice to batch all your DOM changes at once, instead of changing the DOM inside a loop.

```js
const data = [{"1":"ABA NORTH"},{"2":"ABA SOUTH"},{"3":"AROCHUKWU"},{"4":"BENDE"},{"5":"IKWUANO"},{"6":"ISIALA NGWA NORTH"},{"7":"ISIALA NGWA SOUTH"},{"8":"ISUIKWUATO"},{"9":"OBINGWA"},{"10":"OHAFIA"},{"11":"OSISIOMA"},{"12":"UGWUNAGBO"},{"13":"UKWA EAST"},{"14":"UKWA WEST"},{"15":"UMUAHIA NORTH"},{"16":"UMUAHIA SOUTH"},{"17":"UMU - NNEOCHI"}]


let htmlToInsert = ''

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const [[key, val]] = Object.entries(data[i])
  htmlToInsert += `<option value="${key}">${val}</option>`
}


const select = document.querySelector('#profileapplicationform-lga_id')
select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlToInsert)
```

```html
<select name="states" id="profileapplicationform-lga_id">
  <option value="">Select one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Here is what I am getting from the console: https://pastebin.com/U8bUiehy. It doesn't get the key and value correctly

Comment: Is the data returned by your GET request the same as the sample data in your question?

Comment: Double check the line beginning with `htmlToInsert += ...`

Comment: When I ran the code the way you did it without the data I got from the webserver it work but the moment and switch to the dynamic data, it shows
[{"1":"ABA NORTH"},{"2":"ABA SOUTH"},{"3":"AROCHUKWU"},{"4":"BENDE"},{"5":"IKWUANO"},{"6":"ISIALA NGWA NORTH"},{"7":"ISIALA NGWA SOUTH"},{"8":"ISUIKWUATO"},{"9":"OBINGWA"},{"10":"OHAFIA"},{"11":"OSISIOMA"},{"12":"UGWUNAGBO"},{"13":"UKWA EAST"},{"14":"UKWA WEST"},{"15":"UMUAHIA NORTH"},{"16":"UMUAHIA SOUTH"},{"17":"UMU - NNEOCHI"}] on the console but it is scattered in the dropdown list

Comment: I added JSON.parse to the response and I am getting from the webserver and it solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see better your example data and in this case, you need to use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in order to get the key and the value of every object:

```js
const data = [{"1":"ABA NORTH"},{"2":"ABA SOUTH"},{"3":"AROCHUKWU"},{"4":"BENDE"},{"5":"IKWUANO"},{"6":"ISIALA NGWA NORTH"},{"7":"ISIALA NGWA SOUTH"},{"8":"ISUIKWUATO"},{"9":"OBINGWA"},{"10":"OHAFIA"},{"11":"OSISIOMA"},{"12":"UGWUNAGBO"},{"13":"UKWA EAST"},{"14":"UKWA WEST"},{"15":"UMUAHIA NORTH"},{"16":"UMUAHIA SOUTH"},{"17":"UMU - NNEOCHI"}]


data.forEach(item => {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
    html += `<option value="${key}">${value}</option>`;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use jquery and I assume $ already mean jquery

Comment: in this case, the $ is the syntax for template literals, isn't jquery

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
html+= '<option value="' +data[i][0]+ '">' +data[i][1]+ '</option>';
```

You can't get items from objects by index, but you can do

```
data[key] //returns value
```

So your code should go about like this

```
html+= '<option value="' +Object.keys(data[i])[0]+ '">' +data[i][Object.keys(data[i])]+ '</option>';
```

`Object.keys(data[i])[0]` first gets the keys of data[i]. There is only one key, so simply get the first element of the returned array. That is your key.

`data[i][Object.keys(data[i])]` gets an element. It then takes advantage of the `data[key]` property to get the value of that element.

And, instead of using `list.append()`, you can try using `list.innerHTML += html`

Answer (score 0):

something like that ? *(pure JS code)*

```
window.onload =()=>
  {
  const select     = document.getElementById("profileapplicationform-state_origin_id")
    ,   selectList = document.getElementById("profileapplicationform-lga_id")
    ;
  select.oninput =()=>
    {
    selectList.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select one</option>'
      ;
    fetch ( baseurl,  // ??
      {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers(),
      body:JSON.stringify({state_origin_id: select.value})
      })
    .then ( resp => resp.json())
    .then ( data =>
      {
      data.forEach(elm=>
        {
        let [key, val] = Object.entries(elm)[0]
        selectList.add(new Option(val,key))
        })
      })
    .catch ( err => console.log(err) )
    }
  }
```

Javascript **fetch** -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

javascript **new Option** -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option

more question(s)?