# How do I insert JSON data into a dynamic dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to insert my json data into two `<select>`tags. The first dropdown contains the albums, and the second should contain the tracks associated with the chosen album. The first dropdown is filled correctly with my json data, but I'm stuck figuring out why the second dropdown wont completely fill up with the provided data.The end result should be: 
- user chooses album
-> user chooses track
-> track will auto play youtube video in the iframe.

Any help is more than welcome, since I am still new to all of this.

HTML:

```
<body>
<form oninput="play(track.value)">
    <div>Band:
        <select id="artiest">
        </select>
    </div>
<br>
  <div>Track:
      <select id="tracks">
      </select>
    </div>
    <script>main()</script>
</form>

<iframe width="520" height="280" id="player" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; fullscreen" src=""></iframe>
</body>
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "1", "artiest" : "A$AP Rocky", "name" : "Testing",
    "tracks" : [
      {"url" :  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/yEG2VTHS9yg", "titel" :  "L$D", "duration" : "3:58"},
      {"url" :  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Kbj2Zss-5GY", "titel" :  "Praise The Lord", "duration" : "3:25"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id" : "2", "artiest" : "A$AP Rocky", "name" : "AT.LONG.LAST.A$AP",
    "tracks" : [
      {"url" :  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZJM4AQSbZDk", "titel" :  "Love$ick", "duration" : "3:12"},
      {"url" :  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/KfVIRigPyws", "titel" :  "Everyday", "duration" : "4:21"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id" : "3", "artiest" : "Travis Scott", "name" : "Birds In The Trap Sing McKnight",
    "tracks" : [
      {"url" :  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Dst9gZkq1a8", "titel" :  "Goosebumps", "duration" : "4:04"},
      {"url" :  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/tfSS1e3kYeo", "titel" :  "Highest in the room", "duration" : "2:56"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id" : "4", "artiest": "Travis Scott", "name" : "ASTROWORLD",
    "tracks" : [
      {"url" :  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/_EyZUTDAH0U", "titel" :  "BUTTERFLY EFFECT", "duration" : "3:11"},
      {"url" :  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ONRf7h3Mdk", "titel" :  "SICKO MODE", "duration" : "5:13"}
    ]
  }
]
```

JS:

```
// Request
async function getJson(url) {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    return response.json();
}

async function main() {
    let artist = await getJson("jukebox.json");
    let options = "";
    for (var a in artist) {
        options += "<option>" + artist[a].artiest + ":" + artist[a].name + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("artiest").innerHTML = options;

    await showTracks(artist[0].tracks);
    artiest.addEventListener("change", function(ev){
        showTracks(artiest.value)
    })
}

main();

async function showTracks(id) {
    let artist = await getJson('jukebox.json');
    for (let i = 0; i < artist.length; i++){
        var data = artist[i].tracks;
        var urls = "";

        for (var a = 0; i < 2; a++) {
            //urls += '<option>' + data[a].url + '</option>';
            document.getElementById('tracks').innerHTML += '<option>' + data[a].titel + "" + data[a].duration + '</option>';

        }}
}
```

edited:

```
async function main() {
    let artist = await getJson("jukebox.json");
    let options = "";
    for (let a =0; a < artist.length; a++) {
        options += "<option>" + artist[a].artiest + ": " + artist[a].name + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("artiest").innerHTML = options;

    await showTracks(artist[0].artiest);
    document.getElementById("artiest").addEventListener("change", function(){
        var x = document.getElementById("artiest").selectedIndex;
        showTracks(x.index)
    });
}

async function showTracks(artiest) {
    let artist = await getJson("jukebox.json", function () {

    });
        let data = artist.filter(el => el.artiest === artiest)[0].tracks;

        for (let a = 0; a < artist.length; a++) {
            document.getElementById("tracks").innerHTML += "<option>" + data[a].titel + ": " + data[a].duration + "</option>";
        }
}
```

Comment: have a look to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983316/how-to-loop-through-an-array-with-pure-javascript/60983732#60983732

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

These are the problems preventing the tracks `select` from working:

1. `showTracks` doesn't make use of its arguments
2. You're passing `showTracks` an `Array` of tracks, but that function doesn't make use of its arguments
3. You're passing `showTracks` the `value` of a `select` whose options don't explicitly define `value` props. You're better of using `select.selectedIndex` instead of `select.value` there: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp
4. The logic of `showTracks` needs revamping. It needs to do something like:

   - Take the index of the artist (number from 0 to 3)
   - Get the tracks of the artist with the given index
   - Empty the content of the tracks selector
   - For every track in the selected artist's tracks, create an append an option to the tracks selector.

Some recommendations:

1. Use `document.createElement` instead of dealing with `element.innerHTML`. Your code will be easier to understand: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement
2. Review looping methods ([for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and  [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) specially):

```js
// Request
async function getJson(url) {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    return response.json();
}

async function main() {
    let artist = await getJson("jukebox.json");
    let options = "";
    for (var a in artist) {
        options += "<option>" + artist[a].artiest + ":" + artist[a].name + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("artiest").innerHTML = options;

    await showTracks(artist[0].tracks);  // See note 2)
    artiest.addEventListener("change", function(ev){
        showTracks(artiest.value)  // See note 3)
    })
}

main();

async function showTracks(id) {  // See note 1)
    let artist = await getJson('jukebox.json');
    for (let i = 0; i < artist.length; i++){
        var data = artist[i].tracks;
        var urls = "";

        for (var a = 0; i < 2; a++) {
            //urls += '<option>' + data[a].url + '</option>';
            document.getElementById('tracks').innerHTML = '<option>' + data[a].titel + "" + data[a].duration + '</option>';

        }}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'll look into it

Comment: I am stil stuck with this, i managed to get the first two tracks in the select, but I cant figure out how to make it dependent using the index of the first select. Anymore help is greatly appreciated